# How can I solve a circuit of resistances with both a voltage and a current-source in between them?

Tags: electric-circuits

If I have a circuit that consists out of multiple non-parallel/serial resistances with current/voltage sources in between them like the one below
[image: circuit]
How can I solve a system like that (in this case for I_10V and V_0)?. Would I have to do on a thevenin equivalent or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a linear circuit such as this one with multiple sources, you can use superposition:  solve for each source separately (with the others set to zero) and add the results.

Comment: So the total V0 for example is just (v0, for I_source = 0) + (v0, for I_0.1A = 0)?

Comment: Also, if I_source = 0, wouldn't that lead to a short circuit?

Comment: I'm not following your notation.  v0=(v0, with I_source=0) + (v0, with V_source=0).  Also, remember that zeroing a current source means that no current flows through it (it's an open circuit, not a short).

Comment: I think notation is still an issue:  I'm using I_source for the 0.1A independent current source and V_source for the 10V independent voltage source.  Those are the "sources" you set to 0 when using superposition.  It looks like you may be using I_source for the current Ibron in your figure.  Ibron is something you calculate, just like v0, by first setting the 0.1A source to zero, and then the 10V source.  (Of course the details of the calculation are different for the two.)

Comment: Ok, so you have to calculate V_0 twice, once for I_0.1A=0 and once for V_10v=0. The actual V_0 is the sum of these two results, correct? My second concern is: when you say I_0.1A = 0, that leaves a wire without a resistance. Wouldn't that mean any current that passes through the nodes left and right (the ones that connect 5ohm to 10ohm) would choose this new resistance-less path resulting in a shortcircuit? –

Comment: When you say a current source=0, it leaves a wire without current.  No current flows in that branch, by assumption.

Answer (score 0):

i've downloaded NGspice (Next Generation Spice) which is basically an electrical simulator you could get it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngspice/ hoping it helps to answer your question is not GUI based piece of software but instead you should use Netlists which are fine for the purpose.